# cant find source of first in clojure

Tags: clojure

When I go to the source of 'first' this is what I see -

```
(def
 ^{:arglists '([coll])
   :doc "Returns the first item in the collection. Calls seq on its
    argument. If coll is nil, returns nil."
   :added "1.0"
   :static true}
 first (fn ^:static first [coll] (. clojure.lang.RT (first coll))))
```

So following is the source -

```
(. clojure.lang.RT (first coll))
```

What does it mean ? Where is the source of 'first'?

Comment: That's deprecated syntax for Java interop. Now it would be written as `(clojure.lang.RT/first coll)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clojure.lang.RT` is a java class defined in the clojure source. [first](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L651)
is a static method defined on that class.